# Why don't GL_RGB32, GL_RGBA32 exist?

Tags: opengl

Relevant reading: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats

Normalized texture formats, (e.g., GL_RGB8_SNORM and GL_RGB16), store integers that map to floating point ranges (-[1.0,1.0] for signed normalized, [0.0,1.0] for unsigned normalized).

It seems to me like there's a very good reason for having GL_RGB32, GL_RGBA_SNORM, etc. tokens: the precisions would surpass dedicated floating point formats, like GL_RGB32F.  Also, for completeness: why have normalized formats for 8 bits and 16 bits, but not 32?

So, why don't GL_RGB32, GL_RGBA32 exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me like there's a very good reason for having GL_RGB32, GL_RGBA_SNORM, etc. tokens: the precisions would surpass dedicated floating point formats, like GL_RGB32F.

You've just answered your own question. They don't allow it because to allow it would mean either discarding 8 bits of that extra precision in the conversion to single-precision floats, or converting those 32-bit normalized integers to *double-precision* floats.

And you'll notice that not even GL 4.2 allows for double-precision float textures.

It's not allowed because it simply wouldn't be useful on current hardware. Current hardware doesn't support it because supporting it would mean fetching double-precision values from textures.

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought of that.  Neither GLSL nor OpenCL have ways of fetching double precision data.  Completeness is still affected, I suppose.

Comment: @Ian: How is completeness affected? I'd rather the API not offer me options that the hardware doesn't have or won't be able to fulfill (like not actually providing the precision I asked for).

Comment: In the future, if you could sample with double precision, it would be important.  Also, it was initially confusing.  Adding a normalized (u)int32 format wouldn't hurt anything, but it nicely completes the analog with the C types char, short, and int.  When double precision textures come along, I'd argue the same for a normalized (u)int64.